# Two datasets with same parameters in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, dataset

I am trying to create two tables in my SSRS report. I have used 2 different packages  with same parameters for the dataset creation. while executing the dataset2 (manually from data tab in the designer) it works fine and gives me field results. But while executing from report (clicking the view report) the second table , which uses dataset2 , is not returning anything, while the first table does.
Why is this behaviour. Please give me an idea.

Thanks in Advance
Jaz

Comment: How did you solve this problem? It happens exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

I've done the same thing in the past, but it has always worked. Are you parameters named the same and of the same fieldtype?

Answer (score 2):

Look at:
1) Try refreshing fields in the parameter (for some bizarre reason, sometimes RUNNING the query doesn't refresh the fields/parameters for me)
2) Ensure that you are getting the same parameters.  SSRS loves to take 2 datasets that both have the @reportDate parameter and give one of them Parameters!ReportDate and the other Parameters!ReportDate_1
3)As noted by Eppz, are they both the same datatype?